# is there a way to stop executeScript in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

is there a way to stop `chrome.scripting.executeScript` ?

I have this code

```
  const onClick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      const activeTabId = tabs[0].id;
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: activeTabId },
        args: [DURATION],
        func: script,
      });
    });
   // some code...
  }
```

I was searching since 2 days all over the web and I am not able to find a way to stop this script on user interaction.

One way I found is by passing the state on user interaction but it is triggering the script once again. please see the below code

```
    function Popup() {
      const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
      const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
      const [stop, setStop] = useState(false);
    
      const buttonRef = useRef();
    
      const onClick = () => {
        setStop((x) => !x); // change
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
          const activeTabId = tabs[0].id;
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: activeTabId },
            args: [DURATION, stop], // passing the state here
            func: script,
          });
        });
      ....
```

`onClick` is from the popup which changes the state `stop` from `false` to `true`. But the problem is this toggling is calling the script again, please see `onClick` (start/stop connecting) button below

When this button is clicked to stop, I need to find a way to stop executing the script.
Any hints or ideas on this are appreciated.

[image]

Content of the `script.js`

```
function script(duration) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label^="Invite"]');
    chrome.storage.local.set({ timer: buttons.length });
    buttons.forEach((btn, idx) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const button = btn;
        button.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center' });
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }, duration * 1000 * (idx + 1));
    });
  }, 200);
}

export default script;
```

Comment: Show us the contents of your `script` function.

Comment: @wOxxOm script contents added to the Question. Thank YOu!!!

Comment: 1) Add a check inside each setTimeout like `if (window.stopped === true) return;` 2) When disabling from the popup use `func: () => { window.stopped = true }`

Comment: Excellent @wOxxOm can you write it as an answer please along with some stuff on what this `window.stopped` doing? It's a magical moment for me. I struggled for 3 days doing different workarounds. But the way you guided me is a clean one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `executeScript` the code that was injected is running as an independent content script inside the page and no longer depends on executeScript, so you can't just "stop" it.

What you can stop is the loop in your injected code e.g. by checking a global variable before proceeding to the next iteration of a loop or in your case `setTimeout`:

```js
function injected() {
  window.stopped = false;
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // must be a literal value like `true`,
      // otherwise it'll find an element with id="stopped"
      if (window.stopped === true) return;
      el.click();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

To set this variable you can call executeScript like this:

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId: .........},
  func: () => { window.stopped = true },
});
```

**A variation of this approach is to store all timers in an array:**

```js
function injected() {
  if (!Array.isArray(window.timers)) window.timers = []; 
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el => {
    window.timers.push(setTimeout(() => { el.click(); }, 1000));
  });
}
```

...and then cancel them:

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId: .........},
  func: () => {
    window.timers.forEach(clearTimeout);
    window.timers.length = 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, repeated calls to `chrome.scripting.executeScript` are going to execute the script more than once.

The best way to approach this would be with messaging - you can use [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage) to message the content scripts in a given page (including the one you injected).

Your popup would be something like:

```js
function Popup() {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const [stop, setStop] = useState(false);

  const buttonRef = useRef();

  const onClick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      const activeTabId = tabs[0].id;
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTabId, "stop");
    });
  };
}
```

And in your content script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  if (message === "stop") {
    // Do whatever you need to do to stop the script.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try this and then will respond on accepting and upvoting. Thank You!!!

Comment: Hi, I am trying to execute the way you stated, I am sure I am doing wrong some where and getting this error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: Hmm, that would imply that the content script hasn't been injected in to the page. Are you sure that has happened and that you're getting the right tab ID to pass in to `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts on my questions Oliver, I just started creating my first extension 2days ago and I am confused with manifest V2 and V3. I will respond to you once I get familiar with the background scripts and other kinds of stuff. Currently, the accepted answer did the job with `scripting.executeScript`. Thank you once again.